# Find all largest values in a range, across different objects in data frame

Tags: r, filter

I wonder if there is an simpler way than writing if...else... for the following case. I have a dataframe and I only want the rows with number in column "percentage" >=95. Moreover, for one object, if there is multiple rows fitting this criteria, I only want the largest one(s). If there are more than one largest ones, I would like to keep all of them.

For example:

```
object  city    street  percentage
A   NY  Sun 100
A   NY  Malino  97
A   NY  Waterfall   100
B   CA  Washington  98
B   WA  Lieber  95
C   NA  Moon    75
```

Then I'd like the result shows:

```
object  city    street  percentage
A   NY  Sun 100
A   NY  Waterfall   100
B   CA  Washington  98
```

I am able to do it using if else statement, but I feel there should be some smarter ways to say: 1. >=95 2. if more than one, choose the largest 3. if more than one largest, choose them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating an variable that indicates the rows that have the maximum percentage for each of the objects. We can then use this indicator to subset the data.

```
# your data
dat <- read.table(text = "object  city    street  percentage
A   NY  Sun 100
A   NY  Malino  97
A   NY  Waterfall   100
B   CA  Washington  98
B   WA  Lieber  95
C   NA  Moon    75", header=TRUE, na.strings="", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# create an indicator to identify the rows that have the maximum
# percentage by object
id <- with(dat, ave(percentage, object, FUN=function(i) i==max(i)) )

# subset your data - keep rows that are greater than 95 and have the 
# maximum group percentage (given by id equal to one)
dat[dat$percentage >= 95 & id , ]
```

This works by the addition statement creating a logical, which can then be used to subset the rows of dat.

```
dat$percentage >= 95 & id
#[1] TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Or putting these together

```
with(dat, dat[percentage >= 95 & ave(percentage, object, 
                                           FUN=function(i) i==max(i)) , ])

#   object city     street percentage
# 1      A   NY        Sun        100
# 3      A   NY  Waterfall        100
# 4      B   CA Washington         98
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this also in `data.table` using the same approach by @user20650

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[dat[,percentage==max(percentage) & percentage >=95, by=object]$V1,] 
 #   object city     street percentage
 #1:      A   NY        Sun        100
 #2:      A   NY  Waterfall        100
 #3:      B   CA Washington         98
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
 dat %>% 
     group_by(object) %>%
     filter(percentage==max(percentage) & percentage >=95)
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun. I didn't know data.table - will go take a look now.

Comment: @Helene No problem.  For bigger datasets, `data.table` would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
ddf2 = ddf[ddf$percentage>95,]
ddf3 = ddf2[-c(1:nrow(ddf2)),]
for(oo in unique(ddf2$object)){
    tempdf = ddf2[ddf2$object == oo, ]
    maxval = max(tempdf$percentage)
    tempdf = tempdf[tempdf$percentage==maxval,]
    for(i in 1:nrow(tempdf)) ddf3[nrow(ddf3)+1,] = tempdf[i,]
}
ddf3
 object city     street percentage
1      A   NY        Sun        100
3      A   NY  Waterfall        100
4      B   CA Washington         98
```

Comment: I initially did something similar with yours, but I'm trying to avoid for loops. Thanks for your help:)